# Transform this input file into a list of dictionaries, remove duplicate mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

Code:

```
with open('HoCPersons.json.txt') as f:
arrayOfTweets = []
for line in f:
    arrayOfTweets.append(json.loads(line))
```

How to remove *duplicate* data?

here example of data:

> > arrayOfTweets

{u'105824': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Niagara Falls ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Rob Nicholson',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'105825': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Niagara Falls ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Rob Nicholson',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'105826': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Niagara Falls ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Rob Nicholson',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'105835': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Ottawa West\u2014Nepean ',
   u'name': u'Hon. John Baird',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'111555': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'111558': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Central Nova ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Peter MacKay',
   u'province': u' Nova Scotia'},
  u'111559': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'111560': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Battlefords\u2014Lloydminster ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Gerry Ritz',
   u'province': u' Saskatchewan'},
  u'111561': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Battlefords\u2014Lloydminster ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Gerry Ritz',
   u'province': u' Saskatchewan'},
  u'111568': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Battlefords\u2014Lloydminster ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Gerry Ritz',
   u'province': u' Saskatchewan'},
  u'114267': {u'caucus': u'  Liberal',
   u'constituency': u' Wascana ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Ralph Goodale',
   u'province': u' Saskatchewan'},
  u'128127': {u'caucus': u'  NDP',
   u'constituency': u' London\u2014Fanshawe ',
   u'name': u'Irene Mathyssen',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'128153': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'128199': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'128453': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'128529': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'128689': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Central Nova ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Peter MacKay',
   u'province': u' Nova Scotia'},
  u'128694': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Haldimand\u2014Norfolk ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Diane Finley',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'128695': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'128697': {u'caucus': u'',
   u'constituency': u'',
   u'name': u'',
   u'province': u''},
  u'128698': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Parry Sound\u2014Muskoka ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Tony Clement',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'128705': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Calgary Southeast ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Jason Kenney',
   u'province': u' Alberta'},
  u'128706': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Port Moody\u2014Westwood\u2014Port Coquitlam ',
   u'name': u'Hon. James Moore',
   u'province': u' British Columbia'},
  u'128707': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Nunavut ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Leona Aglukkaq',
   u'province': u' Nunavut'},
  u'128711': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Carleton\u2014Mississippi Mills ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Gordon O'Connor',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'128713': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Carleton\u2014Mississippi Mills ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Gordon O'Connor',
   u'province': u' Ontario'},
  u'128717': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Blackstrap ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Lynne Yelich',
   u'province': u' Saskatchewan'},
  u'128718': {u'caucus': u'  Conservative',
   u'constituency': u' Charleswood\u2014St. James\u2014Assiniboia ',
   u'name': u'Hon. Steven Fletcher',
   u'province': u' Manitoba'},
  u'128724': {u'caucus': u'',

Comment: arrayOfTweets=list(set(arrayOfTweets)) convert it into set whose functionality is it does not allow duplicates then again convert it into list

Comment: where is your data? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30608823/edit) your question with your data.